# how to manipulate haystack results in django view

Tags: django, django-haystack

I'm new to haystack.  I have already gone through and implemented this tutorial successfully:  http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html

How do I now get the `queryresultset` of a `basic_search` in my view?

Answer (score 0):

```
def food_log(request):

    query=request.GET.get('q','')
    form=SearchForm({'q': query })

    results = form.search() 

    print results



    context = {
        'form':form,
        'query':query,


    }

    return render(request, 'log.html', context)
```